# Probability of collision of athletes in a cube

Tags: probability, collision-detection

8 Athletes are standing on vertices of a cube. They can run in any direction. Find out the probability that there is no collision. All the athletes have same speed. Athletes can move only on edges. Athletes can be considered as dots.

I have thought the following:

Probability of no collisions + Probability of atleast 1 collision = 1 
This covers the whole spectrum of possibilities.

Changing sides of P(atleast 1 collision).

P(No collisions) = 1 - P(atleast 1 collision)

Further expanding probability of at least one collision:

P(atleast 1 collision) =  P(1 collision) + P(2 collisions) ..... P(12 collisions).

I am unable to proceed further.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with *learning*, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: Do *collisions* happen on edges or at vertices or both?

Comment: The question is highly unclear. Can an athlete change direction? What happens when she reaches an edge, or a corner?

Comment: Does "any direction" mean "only along the edges", or can they start to run out on the faces? What does an athlete do when he reaches another edge or a vertex? Do they stop, or continue going?

Comment: Are the athletes envisaged as having zero size, or are they real physical beings?

Comment: Why do you stop at $12$ collisions? When an athlete comes to a corner, she has three possible ways to continue. Does she choose each with probability one-third? or is she forbidden from making a U-turn, and chooses from the other two directions, each with probability one-half? Do they keep running forever? (If they do, I bet the probability is unity that they eventually have a collision, indeed, infinitely many collisions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by looking at some one athlete. It picks direction and runs. In order not to collide with the athlete who stood on the other side of the edge, that other athlete should have picked any other direction. Etc.

If you carefully proceed on the edges - they form a cycle. Any athlete is on some cycle. on the cube smallest cycle is of length $4$. Therefore the only possible cycle of athletes are $4$ and $8$ ($6$ is not possible, since no cycle of length $2$ - for remaining two athletes is possible)

The first option is two distinct loops of length $4$. Which means two quartet groups of athletes run in parallel planes (see the image below). How many such loops are possible? in each you can pick the direction independently (i.e. $4$ options) and there are $3$ pairs of planes. In total $12$ different ways (not to collide).

[image: athletes running in two loops]

The second option, they all run in the same cycle (see image below). How many such cycles are possible on the cube? I've arbitrary picked a node on the cube and "started" the cycle with colored edges. First two edges uniquely identifies the cycle (try to continue the path after first two and you see you ought to pick very specific turns). Once you have picked a red edge - you have two options to pick the blue one. At the beginning there are $3$ options to set the red edge. And obviously the movement direction on the cycle (two of them). Totaling in another $12$ cycles.

[image: all athletes run in the same cycle]

You  have $24$ ways to pick direction without collisions. And there is obviously $3^8 = 6561$ ways to pick any direction in total.

So, a probability of $0.0036$ to **not** collide.